# Configure which port Spring exposes Websockets over?

Tags: spring, websocket, port, spring-websocket

Maybe i'm missing something obvious but I can't find any information about configuring the port that spring exposes Websockets over from the default 8080 (after looking at http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html).

Does anyone know how to do this? Or if spring allows you to do this?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the port tomcat runs on.  The easiest is to set the port value in your prop file

`/src/main/resources/application.properties`

```
server.port=8888
```

This blog posts should the other ways to do it - https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-how-to-change-tomcat-port/